Weird omp_get_wtime() behavior on cluster (ifort)
I am running the same fortran code on my local windows machine and a cluster.
A mwe of the code would be:
program mwe

use omp_lib    
implicit none
    


integer :: indx
integer :: indy
integer :: indz
integer :: total_z = 1000000
integer :: total_x = 200
integer :: total_y = 100

real, allocatable :: output(:,:), grid_x(:), grid_y(:)
real :: startTime, midTime, totalTime

allocate(output(total_x, total_y))
allocate(grid_x(total_x))
allocate(grid_y(total_y))



do indx = 1, total_x
    grid_x(indx) = indx * 2
end do 

do indy = 1, total_y
    grid_y(indy) = indy / 3
end do 


output = 0.0

startTime = omp_get_wtime()
do indz = 1,total_z
do indy = 1,total_y
!$omp parallel do default(private) shared(indy, total_y, indz, total_z, total_x, output, startTime)    
do indx = 1,total_x  
    
    output(indx,indy) = output(indx,indy) + grid_x(indx)/grid_y(indy) 
    if ((mod(indz, 100000) .eq. 0) .and. (indx .eq. 1) .and. (indy .eq. 1)) then 
            midTime = omp_get_wtime()
            write(*,"(A,F15.1,A)") "Total time elapsed",midTime-startTime," seconds." 
    end if 
    
    
    
end do
!$omp end parallel do  
end do
end do

    
end program

On windows I am compiling the code as:
ifort /O2 /c /Qopenmp main.f90
ifort /o main.out /O2 /Qopenmp main.f90 /link /STACK:999999999,999999999

main.out

And the output is:

Total time elapsed          119.4 seconds.
Total time elapsed          237.8 seconds.
Total time elapsed          357.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed          474.1 seconds.
Total time elapsed          588.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed          730.1 seconds.
Total time elapsed          873.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed         1015.4 seconds.
Total time elapsed         1159.6 seconds.

On the cluster (linux) I am compiling the code as:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -e error_file.err
#SBATCH -p common
#SBATCH -c 40
#SBATCH --job-name==mwe
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
export OMP_STACKSIZE=512mb
source /opt/apps/rhel8/intel-2020/compilers_and_libraries/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64

ifort -O2 -c -qopenmp main.f90
ifort -o main.out -O2 -qopenmp main.f90

./main.out

and the output is:

Total time elapsed            0.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed            0.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          128.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          128.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          128.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          256.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          256.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          384.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          384.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed          384.0 seconds.


The above is not a mwe. We need a complete program, not a snippet. Please see here and edit your question appropriately.

What do you mean "it always prints the same numbers: 128, 256, 384, 512, 640"? Please edit the question to include some of the actual output from both runs.

Have you checked on the cluster how many threads are actually being used in the parallel region?

I do not know what you mean by mwe but we need a MRE [mre]. Note the "reproducible". It must be reasonably complete and self-sufficient.

Thank you for all the comments. I have updated the question accordingly.

The timer has a limited resolution. And it is relying on the runtime library of the specific system.

You can try other timers such as system_clock. You might have a race condition in midTime.

omp_get_wtime returns double precision and not real

@Joachim That shouldn't be a problem, at least not here. You'll just get a type conversion.

@IanBush That shouldn't be a problem, but it turns out that this is actually the problem. Declaring starttime and midtime as double precision fixes the problem. This is a compiler bug of ifort that I already encountered in the past.

@PierU Wow, that is utterly bizarre. Don't use intel a lot so haven't come across that horror.

Sorry, I'm wrong, the right explanation comes from the answer by @VladimirFГероямслава (that said I'm quite sure I encountered a real compiler bug around the omp_get_wtime() function in the past with an older version of ifort)

You are computing a difference of two large numbers. But with the default real, you do not get sufficient precision.
Compare
Total time elapsed   1717144796.8   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.0   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.1   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.2   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.4   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.5   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.6   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.8   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144797.9   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.1   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.2   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.3   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.5   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.6   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.7   1717144796.7 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144798.9   1717144796.7 seconds.

with double precision and
Total time elapsed   1717144832.0   1717144832.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144832.0   1717144832.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144832.0   1717144832.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144832.0   1717144832.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144832.0   1717144832.0 seconds.
Total time elapsed   1717144832.0   1717144832.0 seconds.

with real, for a modified code
write(*,"(A,F15.1,F15.1,A)") "Total time elapsed",midTime,startTime," seconds." 

You need sufficient precision to store the floating point number times. The timers are specific to different compiler suites on different operating systems and will differ. I get different results with Intel and GCC. If you get larger or smaller starting times you will see smaller or larger effective resolution when using real.
The actual precision of the timer is given by omp_get_wtick() but is only achievable when using high enough kind of a real to store the time.
